# Instagram Requirements For Callback URL

Tags: php, curl, instagram

Recently I had a problem on subscribing to a tag. I get this error:

```
Array ( [meta] => Array ( [error_type] => APISubscriptionError [code] => 400 [error_message] => Unable to reach callback URL "insert my url here". ) ) ""###
```

even though my url can be accessed globally.
In the [documentation](http://instagram.com/developer/realtime/), it says that the callback url must support GET and POST methods. My
callback url passed that requirement but I am still getting the error.
Can somebody tell me what I am missing?

Comment: What is the callback URI?

Comment: Hi Sir PeeHaa, can i give this to you in private?

Comment: Nope I don't do private session with strangers. Sorry :)

Comment: That URI is not accessible  https://requestable.pieterhordijk.com/7Nd7o. So the error tells you exactly what is wrong.

Comment: Sorry, can you please elabore more on how come is it unaccessible when i can access it in my browser?is it on my firewall settings?

Comment: Impossible to say without knowing the infrastructure and settings.

Comment: Thank you, do you have any suggestions for this?

Comment: When using `https` instead of `http` the subscription went just fine